# Can we add the 'spam' and 'rude or abusive' reason for flagging on 'close' so then voters can vote to close it as 'spam or rude/abusive'?

Tags: feature-request, moderators, vote-to-close

[This question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43195/delete-this-question) that has been vandalised by its author and other questions that are spam/rude or abusive needs to be closed down.

However, the **only way to close it down for the reason of being spam or rude/abusive is for a moderator to do it.**

The only problem with is that moderators cannot be on the site all the time and some look like they haven't go on the site in years([Ansari](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/18/ansari)).

If all moderators on a site were inactive, **how could one close a question if it is spam/rude or abusive? Inappropriate content can affect people.**

This is why I am requesting for more reasons to close a post added to the options list when closing such as '*spam*' or '*rude/abusive*' so users that are able to vote can close it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, we don't need spam/rude/abusive as close reason.**

Spam or rude/abusive posts should be *flagged* respectively. Closing only prevents them to be answered, but they generally need to be removed instead. From [Vote to close or flag as spam (or both?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96007),

> You should always *flag* spam.
>
> All other actions as are entirely optional. For example, voting to close a spam question (assuming you've already flagged it!) isn't going to do any harm, but probably won't achieve much either (unless the question ultimately *isn't* spam, but just off-topic, in which case you might still help close it).
>
> But, just taking secondary actions (like closing) *without* flagging will potentially slow-down the removal of the offending content.
>
> ---
>
> And, in case you are not aware, after receiving 3 spam flags a post is removed from the front page, and after receiving 6 users flag something as spam it is automatically incinerated - zero moderator intervention required.
>
> For further information see the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) page [How does the spam flag work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work).

Also, [any users with a minimum of 15 rep can flag any posts](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), including flag as spam or rude/abusive. In general (and ideally), you don't need moderators to remove the post (though, they can easily nuke the post *and also the account*).

Alternatively, you could come to [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) or [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) chat room to report the spam/rude post to garner more needed flags.